# Avoiding "select into" error in PL/SQL when filtering a table with a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

In the following minimal PL/SQL query example, I can't get the query to work, in order to filter records from a table based on a certain date, which is stored in a variable.

The goal obviously is to end up with different query results, by changing the date variable to some other moment, different from `sysdate`.

This query does succeed in printing the calculation date variable's content, but the select query afterwards fails with `ORA-06550: line 6, column 3`  (so on 'select *' below) `: PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`.

```
DECLARE
  v_calculation_date date := sysdate;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line(v_calculation_date);
  
  select *
  from t
  WHERE to_number(to_char(trunc(t.some_date), 'YYYYMM')) 
        BETWEEN to_number(to_char(add_months(v_calculation_date,-24), 'YYYYMM')) 
        AND to_number(to_char(add_months(v_calculation_date,-1), 'YYYYMM'));
END;
```

OK, with a SELECT INTO then... This again prints the calculation date variable's content just fine, but the select query afterwards again fails, with the same error:

```
DECLARE
  v_calculation_date date;
BEGIN
  select sysdate into v_calculation_date from dual; -- dual is a dummy table with only one row and one column, just what we need here.
  dbms_output.put_line(v_calculation_date);
  
  select *
  from t
  WHERE to_number(to_char(trunc(t.some_date), 'YYYYMM')) 
        BETWEEN to_number(to_char(add_months(v_calculation_date,-24), 'YYYYMM')) 
        AND to_number(to_char(add_months(v_calculation_date,-1), 'YYYYMM'));
        
END;
```

I already have a SELECT INTO, why is the normal SELECT, which follows afterwards, then refused?

For the sake of completeness: this is a minimal query example for easy reproduction of the problem. My actual query is more complex, I eventually want something like this to work:

```
DECLARE
  v_calculation_date date;
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE t1;

  CREATE TABLE t1 as (
     WITH intermediary1 AS (
       -- The actual query from above, as a subquery
       SELECT *
       FROM t
       WHERE to_number(to_char(trunc(t.some_date), 'YYYYMM')) 
        BETWEEN to_number(to_char(add_months(v_calculation_date,-24), 'YYYYMM')) 
        AND to_number(to_char(add_months(v_calculation_date,-1), 'YYYYMM'));
    )
  )
  
  /* other drops, creates, inserts ... */

END
```

What is wrong in my query?
Execution info: the SQL dialect is PL/SQL, the IDE is PL/SQL Developer version 13.0, the database server runs Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.

Answer (score 2):

In PL/SQL, every `SELECT` (that isn't part of a cursor) must have an `INTO` clause. Therefore, it's not enough that *one* of your `SELECT`s has it.

As of your final code (the one that contains `CREATE TABLE`): that won't work. DDL can't be executed from PL/SQL, unless you use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`). Therefore, all your "other drops, creates, ..." will also have to be *dynamic*.

Note that we usually do **not** create objects *dynamically*; create table at SQL level. Then, if you want to populate it with different data, do so (either from SQL or PL/SQL). First delete "old" data - you can use `delete` or `truncate` (but it is DDL so - as you already know by now - it requires `execute immediate`), and then re-populate the table.

Dynamic SQL is difficult to debug. Don't use it if you don't have to.

If you're concerned about *your own data* so that other users wouldn't interfere, consider creating a global temporary table (or private; depending on database version you use).

---

**[EDIT, based on your comments]**

I'm afraid you're misinterpreting reality. DDL can't be executed in PL/SQL unless it is dynamic SQL. Your "final" code is an anonymous PL/SQL block (I'm talking about the last code you posted, the one that begins with the `DECLARE`, contains `DROP` and `CREATE` table t1) so it **can not** execute those statements as you posted.

Here's a demo. I don't have your tables so I'll *mimic* what you're doing, using Scott's sample `DEPT` table instead on my 11gXE database.

Does the WITH factoring clause work? Yes.

```
SQL> with intermediary1 as (
  2    -- The actual query from above, as a subquery
  3    select *
  4    from dept
  5     where 1 = 1
  6  )
  7  select * from intermediary1;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

Does it work with the `CREATE TABLE`? Not on my 11gXE:

```
SQL>   create table t1 as (
  2      with intermediary1 as (
  3        -- The actual query from above, as a subquery
  4        select *
  5        from dept
  6         where 1 = 1
  7      )
  8      select * from intermediary1
  9    );
  )
  *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause
```

I tried it on apex.oracle.com which runs 18cEE - doesn't work either.

[image]

Maybe your database version supports it, can't tell as I don't have any higher database version to try it on.

But OK, doesn't matter, that's easily fixed by moving a CTE into a subquery:

```
SQL> create table t1 as
  2    select *
  3    from (-- The actual query from above, as a subquery
  4          select *
  5          from dept
  6          where 1 = 1
  7          );

Table created.
```

So, everything is OK with the query itself, it won't cause my PL/SQL block to fail because of it.

OK, so - let's try it, the way you say you use frequently.

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_calculation_date date;
  3  begin
  4    drop table t1;
  5
  6    create table t1 as
  7        select *
  8        from (-- The actual query from above, as a subquery
  9              select *
 10              from dept
 11              where 1 = 1
 12              );
 13    /* other drops, creates, inserts ... */
 14  end;
 15  /
  drop table t1;
  *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DROP" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge


SQL>
```

Whooops! There's an error on `DROP`. Let's remove it and leave `CREATE TABLE`:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_calculation_date date;
  3  begin
  4    -- drop table t1;
  5
  6    create table t1 as
  7        select *
  8        from (-- The actual query from above, as a subquery
  9              select *
 10              from dept
 11              where 1 = 1
 12              );
 13    /* other drops, creates, inserts ... */
 14  end;
 15  /
  create table t1 as
  *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-06550: line 6, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
raise return select update while with <an identifier>
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge


SQL>
```

Whoops #2! Error on `CREATE TABLE`. Looks like *your way* doesn't really work. Let's try it *my way*, using dynamic SQL:

```
SQL> declare
  2    v_calculation_date date;
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'drop table t1';
  5
  6    execute immediate (
  7      'create table t1 as
  8        select *
  9        from (-- The actual query from above, as a subquery
 10              select *
 11              from dept
 12              where 1 = 1
 13              )'
 14              );
 15    /* other drops, creates, inserts ... */
 16  end;
 17  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from t1;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Now it works.

I'd be more than happy if you demonstrate the way you're doing it **without** dynamic SQL. Please, post your own SQL*Plus session (just like I did). Or, if you use some GUI, post a screenshot, no problem.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I don't understand what you mention about my "final code" (the one with multiple statements and DDL combined): I have run it already multiple times and it works, without using an `execute immediate`. Therefore I don't understand why you suggest that this script must be made *dynamic* (using execute immeditate). I do however indeed create tables with intermediary results multiple times during the script, in each next step I proceed by doing further selects on the last intermediary table.

Comment: So the question is: can you help me understand why my DDL statements require dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).

Comment: Additionally: I don't need a temporary table (`CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table`), I have no problem that other users can see the results I have in the intermediary tables I create.

Comment: I edited the answer and added some more info. Have a look, please.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a PL/SQL block for your query and can simplify it to:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -24) <= some_date
AND    some_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM');
```

If you want it in a PL/SQL block then you want to use `SELECT ... INTO ...` if the query is going to return a single row:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_calculation_date DATE := SYSDATE;

  v_col1      T.COL1%TYPE;
  v_col2      T.COL2%TYPE;
  v_some_date T.SOME_DATE%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT col1,   col2,   some_date
  INTO   v_col1, v_col2, v_some_date
  FROM   t
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(v_calculation_date, 'MM'), -24) <= some_date
  AND    some_date < TRUNC(v_calculation_date, 'MM');

  -- Do something with the variables.
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_col1 || ', ' || v_col2 || ', ' || v_some_date );
END;
/
```

If you can return multiple rows then use `SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO ...` or use a cursor:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_calculation_date DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM   t
    WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(v_calculation_date, 'MM'), -24) <= some_date
    AND    some_date < TRUNC(v_calculation_date, 'MM')
  )
  LOOP
    -- Do something with the cursor.
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( cur.col1 || ', ' || cur.col2 || ', ' || cur.some_date );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5648ba394a4f2cf5f14bb081273e799c)*

---

Again, for your more complicated query, you do not need PL/SQL (and cannot have DDL statements in a PL/SQL context):

```sql
DROP TABLE t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 as
SELECT *
FROM   t
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -24) <= some_date
AND    some_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM');
```

---

Or, if you want to use PL/SQL then do the DDL statements in the SQL context and then switch to PL/SQL for the DML statements:

```sql
DROP TABLE t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 AS
SELECT * FROM t WHERE 1 = 0;

-- or
-- TRUNCATE TABLE t1;

DECLARE
  v_calculation_date DATE := SYSDATE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO t1
  SELECT *
  FROM   t
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(v_calculation_date, 'MM'), -24) <= some_date
  AND    some_date < TRUNC(v_calculation_date, 'MM');
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi @MT0, I *do* need a variable for my query, as the "sysdate - X months" is used about 10 times in the statements throughout the script that I made. Up til now I did the manual work of executing that script a few times, by manually replacing X in all occurrences of "sysdate - X months".

Comment: waw, the second query you suggested (with the cursor) looks complex and less readable (IMO) for anyone that would take over my script. I was really looking for a solution  similar to how I would have done it years ago in T-SQL like DECLARE @v_calculation_date DATE; SET @v_calculation_date = SYSDATE; SELECT * FROM t WHERE to_number(to_char(trunc(t.some_date), 'YYYYMM')) 
        BETWEEN to_number(to_char(add_months(@v_calculation_date,-24), 'YYYYMM')) 
        AND to_number(to_char(add_months(@v_calculation_date,-1), 'YYYYMM'));`. I'm surprised to how difficult it seems in PL/SQL.

Comment: @SanderVandenHautte You **CANNOT** run DDL statements in a PL/SQL context. You either need to run it in SQL or you can create dynamic SQL strings in PL/SQL and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run the strings in an SQL context.

Comment: @SanderVandenHautte Updated the end of the answer with another option.